# Basic authentication in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a RESTful back-end server with basic authentication. Currently I am implementing a front end page with AngularJS to interact with the server. Can anyone give me some hint about implementing the basic authentication in AngularJS? Do I need to use Interceptors?

Thanks

Comment: In node I've used the basic-auth module on an express app which hosted both my API & angular app. Everything was in the same place which made it easy. You should use https if you're using basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

By basic authentication did you mean HTTP Auth? Anyway - if you need to send authenticated requests from Angular to your back-end server, then yes you would need to use HTTP interceptors.

I found this article very helpful when I was implementing token based auth w/ Angular before: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/ - but there are a lot of resources out there on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post method and handle the result(i.e., if login Success set some flag success to true else set success to false).

```
backendURL = "http://someurl";
postData = { username: 'USERNAME', password: 'password' };
$scope.serverCall = $http.post(backendUrl, postData);
$scope.serverCall.success(function(result,status,header,config){ //handle your result })
$scope.serverCall.error(function(result,status,header,config){ //handle your Exceptions })
```

Note: Login fail or Success it will come to `success` callback only. In case Exceptions in the backend then only it will come to the `error` callback.

In the Backend Side

```
{ success: true } // If Login Success
{ success: false } // If Login Fail
```

Based on this flag you can handle it.

I Hope this will helpful.